# How to assign asset image to Fancy Shimmer image flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

help me out I am using fancy Shimmer Image flutter dev package, but it only accept network images! I want to assign asset image how can I achieve that?

```
FancyShimmerImage(
                            boxFit: BoxFit.contain,
                            imageUrl:'Network image goes here ',
                            errorWidget: Image.network('Network image goes here '),
                            shimmerBaseColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                            shimmerHighlightColor: Colors.grey,
                            shimmerBackColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                          ),
```

Comment: We normally display shimmering if try to fetch something . But if you want to display image from asset, why you need shimmering? 
Sorry I'm just curious.

Comment: just like u said try to fetch

Answer (score 0):

You put like this

```
FancyShimmerImage(
                        boxFit: BoxFit.contain,
                        imageUrl:'',
                        errorWidget: Image.asset('images/lake.jpg',width: 600.0, height: 240.0, fit: 
                        shimmerBaseColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                        shimmerHighlightColor: Colors.grey,
                        shimmerBackColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                      ),
```